# Detect Connection Aborted on Streaming

Tags: php, nginx, video-streaming, httpurlconnection

Using PHP to read streaming link , i would like to detect when user disconnected mean closed Player so i can make stats up on disconnecting time

However it seem the connection_aborted not been executing...

here you my example :

```
ob_end_clean(); //Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
ignore_user_abort(true); //TRUE ignores user aborts in a script

$file = "http://192.168.1.2:8000/hls/250.m3u8";
header("location: $file");

$fd = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($fd)) {
    echo fread($fd, 1024 * 5);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    if (connection_aborted()){
//this part not executing...
    $ManagerActiv->deleteClient_activity($activity);
    break;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);

exit();
die(); 
}
```

Comment: anyone got an idea ?